# qemu-system-x86_64w.exe : could not open disk image D:\img.img: Permission denied

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, qemu

I'm trying to use qemu on Windows (8), because I have to emulate an USB mass storage device (VirtualBox still doesn't handle USB3 which my computer only have .. and if I could have qemu working it could be great), and I'm getting an error that I can't get off.

In few lines :

```
qemu-system-x86_64w.exe -k fr -boot menu=on -m 256 -L Bios -usb -usbdevice disk:format=raw:D:\img.img Olive1.vmdk
```

Results in :

```
qemu-system-x86_64w.exe: -usbdevice disk:format=raw:D:\img.img: could not open disk image D:\img.img: Permission denied
qemu: could not add USB device 'disk:format=raw:D:\img.img'
```

I tried :

- to run as administrator
- to put a relative path
- to check file permissions/set all users to readable
- to use the \.\D:\img.img notation
- to change \ by /

But I'm still getting this error (and Invalid Argument when it can't get the file, because of a wrong path).
I get the same error when trying to use this image as sdcard (-sd d:\img.img), but removing this file make the VM starting (Olive1.vmdk can be read).

Also :

```
qemu-img.exe info D:\img.img
image: D:\img.img
file format: raw
virtual size: 490M (513470464 bytes)
disk size: 479M
```

qemu-img can read this file

Any idea/help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QEMU must have write permissions to the disk image, otherwise it complains with "Permission denied" error. The solution is to mark the file writable by unchecking the "read-only" box at the file properties.

Comment: @Alex131089 If you want to have a throw-away image `test.img` based on `base.img`, then you can run `qemu-img create -b base.img test.img`. In this way, you can keep `base.img` read-only and make `test.img` writable. Just FYI.